# How to compare lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have 3 lists like this:

```
general_list = ['P' ,      'J' ,   'C',   'H' ,     'O']

real_list    = ['Python', 'Java' , 'C' , 'Html' , 'Other']
```

and another list called

```
selected_items = [ 'Python' , 'Php']
```

I want to compare the `selected_items` with `real_list` so I can have a result when element is in the list put `0 or 1,` so I want to do something like this:  `[ 1 , 0 , 0, 0 , 1]`
and then to check when items in general_list are selected and to get the result like this `['P' , 'O']`

I really don't have an idea how to do this?

Comment: anything tried so far?

Comment: Should give it  a try?..Pencil and Paper would be a good start?

Comment: @MSeifert I just don't know where to start, so for that I asked for any idea, because I don't want someone to code for me but just to give me a hint

Answer (score 1):

It seems an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If what you really want is to use `selected_items` to obtain the final result, then:

```
this_is_useful = {'Python': 'P', 'Java': 'J', 'C': 'C', 'Html': 'H'}
```

And then you can check if `'Python'` belongs by doing

```
if 'Python' in this_is_useful:
    print "Yes!"
```

To obtain your final result:

```
selected_items = [ 'Python' , 'Php' ]
result = [this_is_useful.get(l, 'O') for l in selected_items]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two list comprehensions:

```
inlist = [True if x in selected_items else False for x in real_list]
result = [v for i, v in enumerate(general_list) if inlist[i]]
```